# how can I set up the mail host so I can user one for production and one for development Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have the following in my mailer:

```
#activate board first using a different email?
def welcome_manager(participant)
  @participant = participant
  @user  = participant.user
  @board = participant.board
  @url   = birthday_url(@participant.token, :host => "birthday-greeting.net")
  mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "Confirmation: #{@board.bp_name.possessive} Happy Birthday Board Created" )
end
```

Which uses the host online.
However when I am in development I want to use localhost:3000 as follows:

```
#activate board first using a different email?
def welcome_manager(participant)
  @participant = participant
  @user  = participant.user
  @board = participant.board
  @url   = birthday_url(@participant.token, :host => "localhost:3000")
  mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "Confirmation: #{@board.bp_name.possessive} Happy Birthday Board Created" )
end
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should setup your mail host in the respective `config/environment/development.rb` and `production.rb`.

However, if you really need to do it inline like that, just use a conditional on Rails.env:

```
:host => Rails.env == "production" ? "birthday-greeting.org" : "localhost:3000"
```